# Try catch error

Tags: java

I have these 2 methods to read a number of integers from a file and insert them in a tree. It works fine if the file is found but if the file is not found it doesn't print "File not found". Why is it not going into the catch statement? Thanks!

```
public static void openF(Tree myT)
{

    try
    {
        x=new Scanner(new File("Number.txt")); 
        readF(myT);
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        System.out.println("File not found");
    }
}


// to read from the file
public static void readF(Tree myT)
{

    while(x.hasNext()) //keeps going till it reaches the end of file
    {
        int a =x.nextInt();
        myT.insert(a); //insert in tree

    }
}
```

Comment: File's constructor will only throw an exception if a null pointer is passed to it.  An exception will not be thrown if the file doesn't exist.  Does the Scanner constructor throw any exceptions?  the readF method doesn't

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I tested a simplified version of your code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    try {
        new Scanner(new File("H:\\Hello.txt"));
        System.out.println("The file exists.");
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("File not found: " + e.getMessage());
    }
}
```

When the file exists, it prints `The file exists.`. If not, it prints `File not found: H:\Hello.txt (The system cannot find the file specified)`.

So no, the catch block is running as expected. The error is somewhere else in your code, but given that you're not providing the full code, nor a part which actually compiles (`x` is not declared), there is no way for us to guess where the actual error is.